# Finding Value of C to Maximize Area

Tags: calculus, integration, derivatives, area

$f(x)=xe^{-\sqrt x}$

Find the value of $c$, such that the area bounded between the graph, the $x$-axis, $x=c$, and $x=c+1$ is maximized. Find the maximum area.

I don't know where to start with this one. I need help finding the maximum area.

Comment: Do you know how to integrate your function? If so, then integrate with bounds c to c+1. You will have a function of c. Derive it and find maximum.
Good luck!

Comment: Yes I can find an integral. I suppose c, c+1 represent some number. That is why they are bounds. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

\begin{align*}
  F(x)  &= \int f(x) \, dx \\
        &=-2e^{-\sqrt{x}} \left( x^{3/2}+3x+6\sqrt{x}+6 \right) \\
  A(c)  &= \int_{c}^{c+1} f(x) \, dx \\
        &= F(c+1)-F(c) \\
  A'(c) &= f(c+1)-f(c) \\
  \therefore \: \: 0 &= (c+1)e^{-\sqrt{c+1}}-ce^{-\sqrt{c}} \\
  c & \approx 3.526 \\
  A''(c) &= e^{-\sqrt{c+1}} \left( 1-\frac{\sqrt{c+1}}{2} \right)-
            e^{-\sqrt{c}} \left( 1-\frac{\sqrt{c}}{2} \right) \\
  A''(3.526) & \approx -0.017 \\
             & < 0
 \end{align*}

The root gives maximal area.